# Rewriting this loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, url-rewriting

Need help to rewrite this loop, I feel like I'm way off and sure its not the right way to go about it, and its the only stopping my program from running. Can anyone lead me in the right direction please. If you need anymore info just let me know

```
//--modifier
  void student::completedCourse(double credits, double numericGrade)

  {
      my_credits += credits;
      for (my_qualityPoints; credits; numericGrade;) 
  }
```

this is from header file

```
//--modifier
  void completedCourse(double credits, double numericGrade);
  // post: record a completed course by adding credits to my_credits
  //       and incrementing the qualityPoints by (credits * numericGrade)
  //          aStudent.completedCourse(4.0, 3.67)  // a 4 credit A- perhaps
```

Comment: You are not "incrementing the qualityPoints" by anything, and you are not doing "(credits * numericGrade)". As far as I can tell from the comment you don't even need a loop.

Comment: What would you recommend I should do?

Comment: Please see some [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) on formatting and using a `for` loop. Your example does not compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a member variable `my_qualityPoints`, and I also assume `my_credits` is as well.

Not sure why you were doing a loop there; you are on the right track with the `my_credits` increment.

```
void student::completedCourse(double credits, double numericGrade)
{
    my_credits += credits;
    my_qualityPoints += credits * numericGrade;
}
```